# How to convert phone number format to plain number in android

Tags: android

How can I convert a phone number like (581)-111-1234 or what ever phone format to simple plain number format like: 5811111234 in android??

Any idea?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html

Comment: Gaah! Someone phoned in the documentation for that class. *No* pun intended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use PhoneNumberUtils

```
        PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(phoneNumber);
        PhoneNumberUtils.toaFromString(phoneNumber);
```

Comment: this will not remove the + sign in front.

Answer (score 1):

```
PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators("(581)-111-1234");
```

Comment: this will not remove the + sing in front.